# How to write java.Replace regex expression?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression to replace the following in a space delimited file

The file has:

> WORD WORD C F F ANOTHER WORD
>
> ANOTHER WORD D H F ANOTHER ANOTHER

I am trying to get the expression to capture the LAST F between F F and H F.

I wrote this expression but it doesn't process correctly in JAVA.

`\\(\\(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*\\)\\)(\\s+)(F)(\\s+)`

Can anyone help out? I'm trying to use this with String.ReplaceALL.

Thanks.

Comment: I see no F between F F and H F.

Comment: There are no F's between "F F" and "H F" in your test file...

At any rate, it's be something like .*H F.*(F).*F F.*
dot-star matches anything...

Comment: Why are you escaping your capture parens? Doesn't seem like you are looking for parens in your string.

Comment: This is pointless anyway. Let's say there were two "F"s in the string. What would you get from being able to capture the last one? It is returned as a string so you get "F". What does that tell you? Do you want the number of "F"s in your capture? The position of the last "F"?

Comment: Gents...my bad writing. I want the last F and replace with Female or if M I want Male.

Comment: There is still no last F between ff and hf.  Try including an example that shows a before and a desired after.

Comment: Why in the world would you use Java for something that is infinitely more easily accomplished using standard tools instead?

Comment: I think you have been very unclear with your requirements. I suggest you edit your question with exactly what you need to do. An example of a valid input string would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one :

`\\b(F)\\b(?!\\s+\\bF\\b)`

looking for standalone F not followed by another standalone F

Comment: my pleasure, how about a tick on my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]+))(\\s+)(F)(\\s+)

This is the translation of what you have that is a valid regex.

Answer (score 0):

This one matches such strings. But how do you replace?

```
"^.* F ([^ ]*|[ F])*$"
```